# get value of input and redirect to that url which is in the textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have one input textbox and button on my page. actually what I want is --- on click of the button if the textbox is not empty then redirect to URL which is in the textbox... and it should also be redirected when we press enter key in the textbox. I need javascript function for that... I tried many things.. I am totally new...

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="editbox_search" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I have tried

```
function doKey(e) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var x = document.getElementById('<%=editbox_search.ClientID%>');
        var val = x.value;
        if (val == "") {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            window.location = <%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/")%>+'Search/'+val;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.location.replace(newUrl);
```

Or:

```
window.location.href = newUrl;
```